# Multiple inheritance and accessing ambiguous elements

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm trying to do some runtime type information tricks through multiple inheritance and templating, but I hit an issue with ambiguity.

First, a very basic example of what I'm talking about:

```cpp
#include <memory>

struct A { };
struct B : public A { };
struct C : public B, public A { };

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<A> p0 = std::make_shared<B>(); // possible
    std::shared_ptr<A> p1 = std::make_shared<C>(); // impossible

    // Here the compiler obviously whines "‘A’ is an ambiguous base of ‘C’"
    // but if we're especially naughty, we can circumvent it with a void* cast
    // we still can't really use this pointer to anything though.
    A* p2 = static_cast<A*>((void*)new C()); 
}
```

As the comments suggest, I can be especially naughty and completely ignore the type. This mischievousness will get me straight to developer hell and won't let me use the pointer as I wish anyway, so I'm actually fine with just having a base of `std::shared_ptr<B>`. But the second (and slightly closer to reality) example shows that this compromise is not enough:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int current_val = 0;

struct A {
    int runtime_val;
    A(int v) : runtime_val(v) 
    { 
        std::cout << "ACtor with arg: " << v << std::endl; 
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct B : public A {
    static const int global_val;
    B() : A(global_val) {}
};

template<typename T>
const int B<T>::global_val{current_val++};

struct X : public B<X> {};           // Base 
struct C : public X, public B<C> {}; // Leaf
struct D : public X, public B<D> {}; // Leaf

int main() {
    std::cout << "Xval: " << B<X>::global_val << std::endl; // 0
    std::cout << "Dval: " << B<D>::global_val << std::endl; // 1
    std::cout << "Cval: " << B<C>::global_val << std::endl; // 2

    // std::shared_ptr<A> px = std::make_shared<X>(); // Impossible because of ambiguity
    std::shared_ptr<X> p0 = std::make_shared<X>(); // I'm fine with this, really
    std::shared_ptr<X> p1 = std::make_shared<D>();
    std::shared_ptr<X> p2 = std::make_shared<C>();

    std::cout << "p0 val: " << p0->runtime_val << " (X)" << std::endl; // 0     :)
    std::cout << "p1 val: " << p0->runtime_val << " (D)" << std::endl; // 0     :(
    std::cout << "p2 val: " << p0->runtime_val << " (C)" << std::endl; // 0    >:(
}
```

In this example, I use `B<T>::global_val` as a sort of runtime type information on a given type `<T>`. When the program is run I get the following output (I added some extra comments, for clarity):

```
Xval: 0
Dval: 1
Cval: 2
ACtor with arg: 0  -- (p0 initialization)
ACtor with arg: 0  -- (p1 initialization (X base))
ACtor with arg: 1  -- (p1 initialization (D base))
ACtor with arg: 0  -- (p2 initialization (X base))
ACtor with arg: 2  -- (p2 initialization (C base))
p0 val: 0 (X)
p1 val: 0 (D)
p2 val: 0 (C)
```

It seems that the v-table only wants to point to the `X`-base of my `D` and `C` classes. How can I ensure that the `D` and `C` instances' `runtime_val` will point to the leaves of the inheritance tree, and not the base?

P.S. I have tried making the `X` base class purely virtual, but no luck there.

Comment: are you looking for virtual inheritance?

Comment: My compiler accepts the make_shared, with just this change:
`struct C : public B/*, public A */{ };`

Comment: Should B and C share an A or have their own As ?

Comment: you took some effort to explain "the problem" in details, but I have problems to understand what you actually want to achieve. Its not the compilers fault that there is ambiguity, do you want to pick one of them or do you want to have only a single `A` sub-instance?

Comment: If you want a single A, use virtual inheritance. At the moment there is an ambiguity due to C inheriting from A twice (once indirectly).

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I am trying to make an easy way of "registering" classes into a runtime type system (`A`) in an easy manner. Adding a virtual function to `A` that simply returns the value doesn't work either.

By "easy" I mean when you want a new `X`-inherited class (which happens in my code base), let's say class `E` you simply write `struct E : public X, public A<E>` and it automagically generates a number for `E`

Comment: I was suspecting this already before, I think you confuse "virtual inheritance" with "the base class has a virtual method", those are two completely different things. It really seems like virtual inheritance is what you are looking for

Comment: I'll look it up <3

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 the virtual inheritance solved the issue, thanks!

Comment: glad to help, though note that answers better go to answers, putting the solution in the quesiton makes the quesiton hard to understand for future readers and partly invalidates already given answers. You could answer your own question in an answer if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments, @formerlyknownas-463035818 provided the answer: This is essentially "The Diamond Problem", solvable through Virtual Inheritance:

```cpp
/* ... */
template<typename T>
struct B : public virtual A { // <---- Virtual inheritance
    static const int global_val;
    B() : A(global_val) {}
};
/* ... */

struct X : public B<X> { 
    X() : A(B<X>::global_val) {} // Implementation classes should then initialize their A's individually
};
struct C : public X, public B<C> {
    C() : A(B<C>::global_val) {} // Implementation classes should then initialize their A's individually
};
struct D : public X, public B<D> { 
    D() : A(B<D>::global_val) {} // Implementation classes should then initialize their A's individually
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> std::shared_ptr<A> p1 = std::make_shared<C>(); // impossible
> ```

To clarify why this is impossible, it is not possible for the compiler to know which one of the `A`  bases you inted to point to.

If you inted to point to the `A` base of the `B` base, that is possible with an explicit conversion:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> p1 = std::static_pointer_cast<B>(std::make_shared<C>());
```

But there is indeed no way to refer to the direct `A` base, because of the ambiguity. You could introduce additional wrapper to the other base:

```
struct A          {};
struct B  : A     {};
struct B2 : A     {};
struct C  : B, B2 {};

std::shared_ptr<A> p1 = std::static_pointer_cast<B >(std::make_shared<C>());
std::shared_ptr<A> p2 = std::static_pointer_cast<B2>(std::make_shared<C>());
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong:

```
struct B : public A { };
struct C : public B, public A { };
```

C is a B, which in turn is an A.
So asking C to **also** be an A feels wrong.

My compiler warns with:

> 1>D:\projects\scratch\scratch.cpp(6,19): warning C4584: 'C':
>   base-class 'A' is already a base-class of 'B'
>   1>D:\projects\scratch\scratch.cpp(4): message : see declaration of 'A'
>   1>D:\projects\scratch\scratch.cpp(5): message : see declaration of 'B'

And removing the duplicate inheritance fixes the first snippet:

```
struct B : public A { };
struct C : public B/*, public A*/ { };
```

From here, the real question is: Do you need multiple A instances as base ?

Comment: _So asking C to also be an A feels wrong._ Not if you wanted it to be like that. In this case there are two As in C, one inside of B and one inside of C.

Comment: Yeah, but practically, I've never seen it _actually_ needed, in quite a number of different projects.

Comment: You're right, this is a rare construct, haven't seen it yet myself also.

Comment: "From here, the real question is: Do you need multiple A instances as base ?" - Yes I do actually

Comment: @AsgerGitz having `D` inherit `A` twice via two different paths and each `D` instance having two `A` subobjects is not necessarily the same. You will understand the difference, once you read about virtual inheritance. I think what you really want is the first while the latter creates you a problem